# Java - parse json that contians RTL language

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a `json` that contians `RTL`(right to left) language, in my case hebrew, using `JSONObject` (`org.json.JSONObject`):

```
JSONObject row = requestBody.getJSONObject("row"); //requestBody - json, row - the object I want to parse
```

and the `String` with the `hebrew` text:

```
String addr = "";
if(row.has("m_addr")){ //checking if the object has key name 
  addr = row.getString("m_addr"); //setting value
}
```

when viewing the result I get:

```
System.out.println(addr); // :x?x?x?x?x?
```

anyone knows how to set `UTF-8` when parsing `JSONObject`? or any other soulation?

Comment: Let me try. could be.

Comment: Yes it was the same problem, thanks.

Comment: What is `requestBody`? Is that a `JSONObject`? If so, how is that constructed? Are you reading from a `Stream` or `Writer` somewhere and constructing it by passing in that string for it to parse? If so, it appears that you will need to make sure that the input source you're reading from is properly handling the UTF-8 conversion.

Comment: the 'reuestBody' is http post request data, after parsing string it is JSONObject, it is not utf-8 encoded, I found a simler question, thanks.